# Can Not Populate Dropdown When Placing Elements In Table

Tags: php, syntax-error, dropdownbox

I am using php to connect to MS SQL and populate some dropdowns on their own everything works as expected. Its when I attempt to put the elements in a table that I am getting an error at "' . $row['RCC'] .'";
I keep getting a syntax error. Can anyone assist on what I am missing because I am new to PHP that I am lost here, thanks in advance

```
echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Region:</td>
    <td>
    <select name=RCC>;
     <option value='" . $row['RCC'] . "'>"' . $row['RCC'] .'"</option>;
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "" and ' correctly to escape from php stuffs in your string

```
echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Region:</td>
    <td>
    <select name=RCC>;
     <option value="' . $row['RCC'] . '">"' . $row['RCC'] .'"</option>;
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting gives your error away. Your quotes were backwards:

```
echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Region:</td>
    <td>
    <select name=RCC>
     <option value="' . $row['RCC'] . '">"' . $row['RCC'] .'"</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

But that doesn't matter because this code won;t work. You need to put only the `<option>` tags in your loop. Otherwise you are printing out a table for each element in the database:

```
echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Region:</td>
    <td>
    <select name=RCC>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc$result()) {
     echo '<option value="' . $row['RCC'] . '">"' . $row['RCC'] .'"</option>;
}
echo '
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: The error goes away but the drop down will not populate from my table on the server, when you put it as a stand alone element it work fine! any ideas? Here is the entire code:  


echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Region:</td>
    <td>
    <select name=RCC>;
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
 <option value="' . $row['RCC'] . '">"' . $row['RCC'] .'"</option>;
};
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';